# Как подключать.h файлы во вложенных папках qmake?

Tags: c, qt, qmake

### Как подключать.h файлы во вложенных папках в qmake?

Раньше я выполнял данную операцию через `gcc -I ./include`

На данный момент начал пользоваться  qt redactor, где default стоит qmake.

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    ../source/calc.c \
    ../source/deque.c \
    ../source/rpn.c \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    ../include/calc.h \
    ../include/deque.h \
    ../include/rpn.h \
    main.h

FORMS += \
    main.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

---

Как я могу выполнить подобную опцию через qmake, чтобы не указывать относительные пути в  .c файлах.

*.c - потому, что ещё не дошёл до с++*

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH += <path>/<to>/<headers1>  <path>/<to>/<headers2> ...`, или после каждого пути добавлять \ и новый путь указывать на новой строке http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Не работает с ../include на директорию ниже headers

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH +=../include` или `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../include`

Comment: @AlexF         INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../include - сработало

Comment: Оформил как ответ, может пригодиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в .pro файл:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../include
```